# SQL query in between dates does not work for "AM to PM"

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT GETDATE() StartDate
```

2018-03-28 10:24:44.747

```
SELECT GETDATE()+15 EndDate
```

2018-04-12 10:24:44.747

Column `Login` date is type `DateTime`

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Logindate BETWEEN GETDATE()  AND GETDATE()+15
```

I have  around 300 records  that matches the filter condition but I see only 60 records here for these  dates

How can I check for `Logindate` in between  "AM"  till "PM"?

Comment: 300 records that matched filter condition

Comment: Although this `getdate()+15` works it shouldn't be used.  This is best practice, `DATEADD(DAY, 15 GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

What you see as result of `GETDATE()` is the datetime format in 24 hours (so you don't see AM or PM).

If you want to check complete days, use the comparison with `DATE` format, or even better, truncate your `GETDATE()` result time component.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    employee 
where 
    Logindate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) and 
    Logindate < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 16, GETDATE())
```

Note that I'm adding 16 days but the filter is lower than (not including equal).